# org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RpcException: RPC response exceeds maximum data length

Tags: hadoop

I have set up hadoop cluster on 2 machines.
One machine has both master and slave-1.
2nd machine has slave-2.
When I started the cluster with `start-all.sh`, I got following error in `secondarynamenode`'s `.out` file:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RpcException: RPC response exceeds maximum data length; Host Details : local host is: "ip-10-179-185-169/10.179.185.169"; destination host is: "hadoop-master":9000;
```

Following is my JPS output

```
98366 Jps
96704 DataNode
97284 NodeManager
97148 ResourceManager
96919 SecondaryNameNode
```

Can someone help me tackle this error ?

Comment: Can you solve the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exception ": org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RpcException: RPC response exceeds maximum data length" from java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49060244/exception-org-apache-hadoop-ipc-rpcexception-rpc-response-exceeds-maximum-da)

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem.

Please check `core-site.xml`
(this should be under the dir where you downloaded Hadoop, for me the path is: `/home/algo/hadoop/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml`)

The file should look like this:

```
<configuration>
        <property>
                <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
                <value>/home/algo/hdfs/tmp</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>fs.default.name</name>
                <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
        </property>
</configuration>
```

Solution: using `hdfs://localhost:9000` as `ip:port`.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a problem with the port number you are using. Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/60701948/8504709